# Relacionamento de tabelas com os mesmos atributos

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, modelagem, tabela-banco-de-dados, modelo-relacional

Meu sistema é para controle de funcionários.

Onde temos os seguintes tipos de pessoas(ou cargos): agente, analista, supervisor, coordenador e gerente.

Como eu fiz:

Eu criei uma tabela para cada tipo desses, mais+ uma tabela de usuário que contem o login e senha para acessar o sistema.

As tabelas contem quase as mesmas informações, algumas vão ter menos ou mais atributos. Ex: agente tem mais atributos que supervisor.

Problema:

Todas essas tabelas tem em relação a tabela "cargo". 1 cargo - N agentes.

Se eu criar um agente, e futuramente ele se promovido para supervisor, eu só vou alterar o seu cargo, mas ele vai permanecer na tabela "agente".

O que pode ser feito?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A tabela que "manda" aí é a de funcionário, isto é algo concreto. Se a pessoa é funcionária, é ali que ela deve ser cadastrada.

A decisão é apenas onde colocar os dados que dependem do cargo que o funcionário está ocupando naquele momento.

A solução mais simples é colocar todas as colunas específicas de todos os cargos nesta mesma tabela de funcionário e não se importar que várias delas fiquem sempre com valor nulo. Haverá uma coluna indicando o cargo ocupado e a aplicação saberá quais colunas interessam para aquele cargo. Não gosto muito disso, mas é mais viável do que as pessoas costumam imaginar.

A solução que parece mais conceitualmente correta é ter um conjunto de tabelas auxiliares, uma para cada cargo com apenas as colunas específicas necessárias. A tabela de funcionário também terá uma coluna indicando o cargo. A performance tende a ser ligeiramente menor, mas bem aceitável.

Note que essa tabela não é a de cadastro de cargo (essa descreve o cargo em si, de forma geral para todos), é uma que relaciona os dados do cargo para cada funcionário, então se tiver 20 agentes trabalhando na empresa, ela terá 20 linhas.

Pelo que entendi manterá as tabelas atuais removendo apenas as colunas que são comuns para todo funcionário e estas colunas irão para a nova tabela de funcionário que sempre estará relacionada com as de cargos.

Comment: Mas como ficaria os relacionamentos entre Gerente > Coordenador > Supervisor > Analista/Agente.

Comment: Não vejo dificuldade alguma nisso, mas de qualquer forma isto não está na pergunta.

Comment: Procurei aqui algumas informações sobre auto-relacionamento.

Basicamente eu teria a tabela funcionario, que teria dentro dela os atributos como:

id(int, notnull) PK
nome(varchar, notnull)
cargoId(int, notnull) - FK
supervisorID (int, null)- FK (ONDE ESSAS SEGUINTES FK's são a chave primaria da propria tabela funcionario)
coordenadorID (int, null)- FK
gerenteID (int, null)- FK

Então se o proprio funcionário for um "supervisor", ele vai ficar com o campo null.

Correto ?

Comment: Provavelmente..